# ansible lineinfile

Tags: ansible

Задача:

Удалить строку из файла по маске. Но имена у файлов разные $HOSTNAME_war.
Как верно составить плейбук?

Мой вариант не работает:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/"$HOSTNAME"_war
    state: absent
    regexp: '^deleteline*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Ansible есть свои переменные(факты), например:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/{{ ansible_hostname }}_war
    state: absent
    regexp: '^deleteline*'
```

Comment: Я так пробовал. Получал ошибку: что переменная не задана, но при этом в плейбуке у меня включен сбор фактов. Видимо я допустил ошибку в плейбуке - всё сработало.

Comment: Подозрительно. Для проверки сделайте `ansible host -m setup` и убедитесь, что `ansible_hostname` определен – после этого нужно разобраться, почему он не виден в плейбуке (возможно, факты закешированы криво).